# Implementing recaptcha on Github pages without php?

Tags: recaptcha, github-pages, invisible-recaptcha

Absolute newb here, please forgive me for this basic question.

I have built my portfolio site using Github pages, but am experiencing spam via my contact form (hosted by [GetSimpleForm](https://getsimpleform.com/)). I am trying to implement Google reCAPTCHA, but I'm a bit stuck in the backend part. As I understand, Github pages don't support PHP, so I can not actually complete the form verification.

Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) was unfortunately a bit overwhelming and cryptic to me as a beginner, since I just stared at my Github html/css/js files and had no clue what to put where.

Am I trying to do the impossible? Is it possible to use reCaptcha on Github pages? If so, is there a beginner friendly tutorial somewhere or a straightforward "copy-paste" thing I could use? (so far, it's not been clear where to use the secret key from the API key pair for example)

Thanks a bunch for any leads or alternative solutions for spam prevention that would work in Github pages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot. Github Pages only support ***static site***. You have to host your own website if you want to do some complex stuffs like backend check etc. and mostly they are not free.

The only suggestion I can come up is simply change your contact form to regular html form instead of hosting by the 3rd party website you are using. I suspect that the main reason you got spam is because you are using it's service.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am using the GetSimpleForm for the same reason actually, since submitting html forms requires backend and on Github static pages there would be no other way to actually get form contents from visitors. I guess I am indeed trying the impossible and it's time to look at hosting options :) any affordable recommendations while we're at it?

Comment: @AnzuPai as you said, you are a beginner so I cannot really suggest any options for hosting website since it requires a lot of site configurations etc, not even mention you have to create the backend for yourself, which is far more complex than the Recaptcha. I checked the website(GetSimpleForm) you provided, they recommand Akismet to prevent spam, so you might want to check it out. It has free option for personal website.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do it is to make the form with HTML (you can either copy the code from a pre-made HTML site with a form, or find a youtube tutorial that shows you how to make a HTML form, pretty simple), and host it on something like Netlify. Netlify is free for static websites unless you are doing something really complicated, and it has a built in form submission that will send you an email automatically every time someone fills out the form. You don't need PHP or a third party app or anything.

You still create and edit the code of the website through Github, you just need to connect it to Netlify for the forms. I'm a complete beginner and I figured it out. Netfly has some tutorials that explain it nice and simple. No reason to pay or do a lot of complicated stuff, and you can make professional websites with just HTML and CSS.